# ¿Cómo puedo convertir los elemento de una lista string a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por ejemplo, si tengo `l = ["1.0","2.0","3.0","4.0"]` (los números entrecomillas para que sean reconocidos como strings)

¿Como puedo convertir a float cada uno de los elementos de manera sencilla?

El propósito de esto es para poder hallar el máximo con el método `l.max()` de forma correcta, ya que si son strings no da el verdadero valor mas alto desde el punto de vista numérico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Como puedo convertir a float cada uno de los elementos de manera sencilla?

Puedes usar la función implementada [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), esta convierte strings con literales numéricos a números de como flotante.

> Return a floating point number constructed from a number or string x.

Con [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
l = list(map(float, l))
```

Con compresión de listas:

```
l = [float(i) for i in l]
```

Saludos.

Comment: El argumento de *map* no necesariamente tiene que ser un *lambda*, puede ser cualquier objeto que se pueda llamar como función, así que puedes pasarle directamente *float* en vez del *lambda*.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @braver Tienes razón, no lo había pensado. Gracias por la observación.